# Code duplication vs type casting vs?

Tags: java

Lets suppose I have such classes:
ParentA,ChildA1,ChildA2...ChildAn
ParentB,ChildB1,ChildB2...ChildBn

So, every ChildAi class extends ParentA, and every ChildBi class extends ParentB class.

In class ChildAi I need to work with class ChildBi. For example:

```
public class ChildAi extends ParentA{
   public ChildBi getChildB(...){
   ....some logic....
   return childBi;
  }
}
```

So the problem is with method getChildB. If I put this method in ParentA, that I can return only ParentB class and I will always have to do casting. If I put this method in ChildAi than I will always duplicate this method and at least some logic of it. How can I solve it? Is it possible to solve such problem without generics?

Comment: Maybe [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) can help you.

Comment: What makes you wish not to use generics?

Comment: Well, you have stated a few solutions yourself: explicit casting or "duplicated" code. Note that generics in Java are based on implicit casting anyway.

Comment: You know that Java allows covariant returns, right? So you can declare `public ParentB getChildB(...)` in `ParentA`, and then each `ChildAi` class can return the subtype of `ParentB` that it wishes. Why is that not sufficient? Would you need to downcast each object to the appropriate child of `ParentB`? Why? If they don't all have a common API that can be defined in `ParentB` or some interface, are they really subtypes? Is this an LSP violation?

Comment: @David Conrad The problem is that after getting ChildB I need all the logic of ChildBi not only logic of ParentB.

Comment: LSP violation or design problem in general sounds very reasonable. What are those classes doing and why do you try to make them behave that way? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @zapl Thank you for your time. But if I start explain what I need it for, it really will take a lot time. Just believe me - there is no another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that generics is your friend here.

Define class ParentA as folloiwing:

```
public class ParentA<T extends {
   public abstract T getB();
}
```

Now each subclass will define the generic type as following:

```
public class ChildA1 extends ParentA<ChildB1> {
    public ChildB1 getB() { return ...;}
}
```

That's it. No casting and no duplicate code.

Comment: OP is asking for a solution without using generics either.

Comment: @E_net4, I cannot agree with you. OP is looking for _solution_ and does not have (or at least did not provide) any reason against generics. I guess that such reasons do not really exist. This is java-style solution. Other solutions that I can imagine require casting.

Comment: Do note that I was also wondering why OP was not accepting the use of generics. And having no reason for so does not void his original request entirely. In this case your answer should have contemplated some motivation or justification to why generics is the only reasonable way to go, unlike answering as if that part of the question did not exist.

Comment: @E_net4 I agree with you. AlexR, you answered the first part of the question (How to solve it). Thank you very much. But you didn't prove that generics is the only way.